# Atualizar campos de uma classe com nomes sequenciais

Tags: java, java-8

Como atualizar o *background color* de 15 `JTextField` durante um loop? 
Por exemplo, possuo os seguintes `JTextField`:

```
txtEsp1
txtEsp2
txtEsp3
...
```

E quero criar um loop, para setar o background dos 15 como branco:

```
for(int i=1;i<15;i++) {
   txtEsp[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Comment: E qual o problema?

Comment: O problema é que o for como está escrito no post não funciona, qual motivo da negativação do tópico?

Comment: Então forneça um **[mcve]** com o problema porque sua duvida não faz o minimo sentido com esse código.

Comment: Acho que você está procurando por [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entendi o que está tentando fazer, porém o Java não funciona assim. Ao utilizar `txtEsp[i]`, você está referenciando uma posição `i` para uma vetor chamado `txtEsp`, e não para o nome da variável em questão.

Para fazer isto, o Java oferece um recurso chamado Reflection, no qual permite que você acesse recursos da própria classe. Para pegar as variáveis com o nome `txtEspN` é necessário utilizar a seguinte função:

```
public void colorir() {
    for(Field field : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) { // ou ClasseExemplo.class no lugar de getClass()
        if (field.getName().matches("^txtEsp(1[0-5]|[0-9])$")) {
            ((JTextField) field.get(this)).setBackground(Color.WHITE); // ou ClasseExemplo.class no lugar de this
        }
    }
}
```

Neste caso, eu utilizei a expressão regular [`^txtEsp(1[0-5]|[1-9])$`](https://regex101.com/r/LSelpF/2) para validar os números, mas você também poderia validar os números depois de **txtEsp** com `Integer#parseInt()` e verificar se é um número está contido em `1 ≤ N ≤ 15`.

---

### Nota:

Ao utilizar `field.get(this)`, o compilador **pode** não encontrar o campo procurado. Isso deve-se ao fato do Java não permitir o uso de variáveis locais como Fields ao procurá-las. Caso isto aconteça, você deve transformar a variável local em global, colocando-a no escopo da classe.

Comment: Não existe `setBackground` pro tipo Field do pacote reflect.

Comment: @Articuno Obrigado, corrigido.

Comment: Se tiver outros campos que atendam a essa condição e não forem do tipo do cast, vai estourar exceção, pois seu código está pegando todos os campos da classe.

Comment: O OP disse: "Possuo os seguintes JTextField", e logo abaixo tem um loop de 1 à 15 para os objetos. Suponho que não haverá erros relacionados ao cast.

Comment: Obs: Não existe `setBackground` pro tipo Object do pacote lang*.

Comment: Em momento algum ele disse que só tem campos de jtextfield na classe. É preciso tratar pra depois não ocorrer classcastexception.

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo que estava procurando! Articuno, inicialmente possuo apenas os 15 JTextField na tela (É uma tela de Kanban) em que preciso limpar o kanban a cada 3 minutos para gerar um novo.